# Unable to run flutter for Desktop, but can build flutter for desktop (Linux)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop, flutter-linux

My flutter app builds and runs just fine, but I cannot run it in debug mode.
Below is the error I get:

```
Unable to start executable "build/linux/x64/debug/bundle/polls": ProcessException: Failed to find "build/linux/x64/debug/bundle/polls" in the search path.
  Command: build/linux/x64/debug/bundle/polls 
ProcessException: Failed to find "build/linux/x64/debug/bundle/polls" in the search path.
  Command: build/linux/x64/debug/bundle/polls
```

The app name I am working on is called polls, and when I look into the directories, the build/linux/x64/release directory has a directory called bundle with the compiled binary, but the build/linux/x64/debug doesn't have the bundle directory.

How do I make **flutter run -d linux** create the missing directory when compiling the debug version?

My environment configurations are as shown below:

```bash
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Linux Mint 20.3 5.4.0-110-generic, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at /usr/local/src/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (11 days ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
    • Engine revision caaafc5604
    • Dart version 2.17.1
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /home/arthur/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /usr/local/src/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /usr/local/src/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin version 211.7817
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.40.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Linux Mint 20.3 5.4.0-110-generic
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.61

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: do you see anything suspicious when you run `flutter run -v -d linux`?

Comment: No, nothing suspicious, just the same error, Unable to start executable "build/linux/x64/debug/bundle/polls": ProcessException: Failed to find
"build/linux/x64/debug/bundle/polls" in the search path.

Comment: what's the output of `ls -l build/linux/x64/debug/`?

Comment: The response of ls -l =>

build.ninja

CMakeCache.txt

CMakeFiles

cmake_install.cmake

flutter

install_manifest.txt

intermediates_do_not_run

rules.ninja

Comment: what if you remove (or move) `build/linux` folder and try again?

Answer (score 2):

I solved by running `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue, where a sample flutter app, that I created via Visual Studio Code, was unable to find bundle in the path.

As a test, in a completely different directory, from a terminal outside of
Visual Studio Code, I ran `flutter create startup_namer` and was able to
successfully invoke `flutter run -d linux` on it.